# OData V4 Web Service Expanded Property cannot be found

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central, odata-v4, dynamics-al

`Hello, I have Developed multiple Custom APIs to receive Documents and respective Lines. Orders/Shipments/Credits. The data is inserted into one single table if that information is of any help. However, At times, without any changes to the code (API Pages), the Line Property just disappears. I have no better way of saying it. I get the following response 'The property 'shipmentLines' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.NAV.easyShipment'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type. CorrelationId: 18a70822-cc72-4c56-8c48-2a5df03678e8. ' It reappears once we redeploy.

The $metadata (yourbaseurl:port/(ServerInstance)/api/(APIPublisher)/(APIGroup)/(APIVersion)/$metadata) response will show it as:

```
<EntityType Name="easyShipment">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="documentNo" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" />
                <Property Name="customerComments" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="customerEmail" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" />
                <Property Name="customerID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="weight" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="dateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="discountAmount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="discountCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="grandTotal" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="indexNo" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="type" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="orderExists" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
                <Property Name="orderID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="paymentMethod" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="receipted" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="shipmentCount" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="shipmentDate" Type="Edm.Date" />
                <Property Name="shipmentID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="shippingHandling" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="shippingDescription" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="250" />
                <Property Name="shippingMethod" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="store" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="subtotal" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="totalNoOfLines" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="isOrderCompletelySynced" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
                <Property Name="isShopOrder" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
                <Property Name="dimensionCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
</EntityType>
Once we Redeploy, it will be shown as (which is how it should be):
            <EntityType Name="easyShipment">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="documentNo" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" />
                <Property Name="customerComments" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="customerEmail" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" />
                <Property Name="customerID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="weight" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="dateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="discountAmount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="discountCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="grandTotal" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="indexNo" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="type" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="orderExists" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
                <Property Name="orderID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="paymentMethod" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="receipted" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="shipmentCount" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="shipmentDate" Type="Edm.Date" />
                <Property Name="shipmentID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="shippingHandling" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="shippingDescription" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="250" />
                <Property Name="shippingMethod" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="store" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="subtotal" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="totalNoOfLines" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="isOrderCompletelySynced" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
                <Property Name="isShopOrder" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
                <Property Name="dimensionCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="shipmentLines" 

    Type="Collection(Microsoft.NAV.shipmentLine)" ContainsTarget="true" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="shipmentLine">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="calculatorSettings" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="250" />
                <Property Name="dateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="discountAmount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="type" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="lineType" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="name" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="200" />
                <Property Name="orderID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="productOptions" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="qTY" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="receipted" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="shipmentID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="shippingHandling" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="size" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100" />
                <Property Name="sku" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" />
                <Property Name="subtotal" Type="Edm.Decimal" Scale="Variable" />
                <Property Name="webshopLineNo" Type="Edm.Int32" />
            </EntityType>


            
Lastly Even if the Line Property is there in the response. Sometime the Lines would not be received. This happens only on specific Server instances. I do not know if some type of conf is causing this. It works fine on one server and stops receiving lines on the other. The .app on both servers is the same. Even if there are some changes, the API pages are not changed and are exactly the same.
All 3 APIs are structured the same but the line issue is received only on Shipment API. Orders and Credits work fine.
Screenshot of the example code as Shipment API:
 [example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBO8X.png)
[example code ctd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgX94.png)
 
Url Struct:
Baseurl:port/(ServerInstance)/api/(APIPublisher)/(APIGroup)/(APIVersion)/$batch
Request Body:
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "r1",
            "url": "companies(CompanyID)/easyShipments?$expand=shipmentLines",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": {
                "documentNo": "PM-TESTSHP3",
                "dimensionCode": "ABC",
                "shipmentDate": "2021-09-21",
                "shipmentID": "PM-TESTSHP1",
                "store": "Store",
                "orderID": "PM-TESTORD2",
                "weight": 24.28,
                "type": "Insert",
                "shippingDescription": "Ship",
                "shippingMethod": "Ship Method",
                "shippingHandling": 0,
                "customerID": "Cust",
                "customerEmail": "Cust@Email.co.uk",
                "paymentMethod": "Cash",
                "dateTime": "2023-02-15T12:17:54Z",
                "totalNoOfLines": 1,
                "isShopOrder": true,
                "shipmentLines": [
                    {
                        "name": "TSTItem",
                        "sku": "TST",
                        "size":"",
                        "qTY": 1,
                        "shipmentID": "PM-TESTSHP3",
                        "orderID": "PM-TESTORD2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Response:
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "r1",
            "status": 201,
            "headers": {
                "location": "https://YourBaseURL:Port/(ServerInstance)/api/(APIPublisher)/(APIGroup)/v2.0/companies(9848fdb3-4041-eb11-bbfc-000d3ad4efad)/easyShipments(ecf7af9b-aef0-ed11-964f-0022480177a4)",
                "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal",
                "odata-version": "4.0"
            },
            "body": {
                "@odata.context": "https://YourBaseURL:Port/(ServerInstance)/api/(APIPublisher)/(APIGroup)/v2.0/$metadata#companies(9848fdb3-4041-eb11-bbfc-000d3ad4efad)/easyShipments/$entity",
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzQ0OzBhL1k2cTFkZk9oZG43K1MrbGZ4ZnFWR2NoOE1uSmI5S0pMajhhK1BuQnc9MTswMDsn\"",
                "id": "ecf7af9b-aef0-ed11-964f-0022480177a4",
                "documentNo": "PM-TESTSHP2",
                "customerComments": "",
                "customerEmail": "Cust@email.co.uk",
                "customerID": "Cust",
                "weight": 24.28,
                "dateTime": "2023-02-15T12:17:54Z",
                "discountAmount": 0,
                "discountCode": "",
                "grandTotal": "",
                "indexNo": "",
                "type": "Insert",
                "orderExists": false,
                "orderID": "PM-TESTORD2",
                "paymentMethod": "CASH",
                "receipted": "2023-05-12T10:20:25.533Z",
                "shipmentCount": 0,
                "shipmentDate": "2021-09-21",
                "shipmentID": "PM-TESTSHP1",
                "shippingHandling": 0,
                "shippingDescription": "Ship",
                "shippingMethod": "Ship Method",
                "store": "Store",
                "subtotal": 0,
                "totalNoOfLines": 1,
                "isOrderCompletelySynced": false,
                "isShopOrder": true,
                "dimensionCode": "TST",
                "shipmentLines": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
Feel free to ask anymore detail.

I have tried this on multiple servers but i get the issue on one server.`
```